# What happens when publishing messages with EasyNetQ and the bus is disconnected?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm currently investigating this but thought I'd ask anyway. Will post an answer once I find out if not answered.

#### The problem is as follows:

An application calls RabbitHutch.CreateBus to create an instance of IBus/IAdvancedBus to publish messages to RabbitMQ. The instance is returned but the IsConnected flag is set to false (i.e. connection retry is done in the background). When the application serves a specific request, IAdvancedBus.PublishAsync is called to publish a message while the bus still isn't connected. Under significant load, requests to the application end up timing out as the bus was never able to connect to RabbitMQ.

Same behaviour is observed when connectivity to RabbitMQ is lost while processing requests.

#### The question is:

How is EasyNetQ handling attempts to publish messages while the bus is disconnected?

Are messages queued in memory until the connection can be established? If so, is it disposing of messages after it reaches some limit? Is this configurable?

Or is it forcing the bus to try to connect to RabbitMQ?

Or is it dumping the message altogether?

Is PublisherConfirms switched on impacting the behavior?

Comment: Did you get any result on your testing. Im in the same position right now

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to test all scenarios described above, but it looks like before trying to publish to RabbitMQ, EasyNetQ is checking that the bus is connected. If it isn't, it is entering a connection loop more or less as described here: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Error-Conditions#there-is-a-network-failure-between-my-subscriber-and-the-rabbitmq-broker

As we are increasing load, it looks as if connection loops are spiralling out of control as none of them ever manage to connect to RabbitMQ because our infrastructure or configuration is broken. Why are we getting timeouts I have not identified yet but I suspect that there could be a concurrency issue going on when several connection loops attempt to connect simultaneously.

I also doubt that switching off PublisherConfirms would help at all as we are not able to publish messages and therefore not waiting for acknowledgement from RabbitMQ.

**Our solution:**

So why have I not got a clear answer to this question? The truth is, at this point in time the messages that we are trying to publish are not mission critical, strictly speaking. If our configuration is wrong, deployment will fail when running a health check and we'll essentially abort the deployment. If RabbitMQ becomes unavailable for some reason, we are OK with not having these messages published.

Also, to avoid timing out, we're wrapping up message publishing with a circuit breaker to stop message publishing if we detect that the circuit between our application and RabbitMQ is opened. Roughly speaking, this is working as follows:

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.Create(...).Advanced;
var rabbitMqCircuitBreaker = new CircuitBreaker(...);
rabbitMqCircuitBreaker.AttemptCall(() => {
    if (!bus.IsConnected)
       throw new Exception(...);
    bus.Publish(...);
});
```

Notice that we are notifying our circuit breaker that there is a problem when the IsConnected flag is set to false by throwing an exception. If the exception is thrown X number of times over a configured period of time, the circuit will open and we will stop trying to publish messages for a configured amount of time. We think that this is acceptable as the connection should be really quick and available 99.xxx% of the time if RabbitMQ is available. Also worth noting that the bus is created when our application is starting up, not before each call, therefore the likelihood of checking the flag before it is actually set in a valid scenario is pretty low.

Works for us at the moment, any additional information would be appreciated.